# Jquery jparallax yorigin not working

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, parallax

I'm using jparallax on this site http://www.nalacebu.com/ problem is the parallax in the 3 boxes won't scroll vertically. It works if you open and close the browser "source viewer" or simply re-size the browser. It works locally and it's on a wordpress theme.

here's the script:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery('#parallax1 .parallax-layer1')
          .parallax({mouseport: jQuery('#parallax1')},{xorigin: 'center'},{yorigin: 'center'});
        });
```